# Android Alarm Manager not firing at specific time when rebooted

Tags: android

I have a problem with AlarmManager. When device is rebooted, it automatically fires the alarm even though specified time is incorrect (e.g. device rebooted completely at 3:00pm, specified time is 4:00 am)

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
class DeviceBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // Check if successful reboot
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {

        SharedPreferences shared = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // Check if daily notification is enabled
        // If yes, call NotificationPublisher to communicate with NotificationAlarmService
        if(shared.getBoolean(Constants.KEY_IS_DAILY_NOTIFIED, false)) {
            DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
            DBConnector.dbConnect(dbHelper);

            int DAILY_NOTIFICATION_ID = Constants.DAILY_VERSE_NOTIFICATION_1_ID;
            ArrayList<Notification> notificationList = dbHelper.getNotifications();
            Log.e("", "notificationList: " + notificationList.size());

            for(Notification obj : notificationList) {
                Calendar datetime = Calendar.getInstance();
                datetime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, obj.getHourOfDay());
                datetime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, obj.getMinute());
                datetime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

                Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
                if (now.after(datetime)) {
                    datetime.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                }

                Log.e("BOOT RECEIVER", "" + obj.getHourOfDay() + ":" + obj.getMinute());

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationPublisher.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                        DAILY_NOTIFICATION_ID++,
                        myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        datetime.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                        pendingIntent);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".utils.DeviceBootReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

What seems to be wrong with my code? I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Starting alarm service on device reboot, have a look at link http://javatechig.com/android/repeat-alarm-example-in-android

Comment: @bEtTy Barnes: Your code looks good try to reinstall the app and see if it works.

Comment: @kevz I've done that but no avail.

Answer (score 0):

[Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) say:

> If the stated trigger time is in the past, the alarm will be triggered immediately.

So, you should check whether you're setting a past time or not in your app logic.

For example, in your `BOOT_COMPLETED` receiver, where you're setting the alarm, you can check whether it's a valid time or not. Another option would be in your target component being triggered, you can check for this.

Comment: Thanks! Can you provide some sample codes to get started with?

Comment: Also, this happens when trigger time is later than the current time.

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes The logic is simple! Check whether the currently being set time is _before_ the current time, if so don't schedule alarm manager for these kinda times.

Comment: So how can I schedule the alarm?

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/05/android-alarm-manager_31.html

Answer (score 0):

If you set alarm for past time, it will fire immediately.You have to check it manually before setting alarm.

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            // Set alarms
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();


            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
                    context, 0, intent1,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            long triggerMillis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

            if (calendar.getTimeInMillis() < Calendar.getInstance()
                    .getTimeInMillis()) {
                triggerMillis = calendar.getTimeInMillis() + INTERVAL_DAY;

                System.out.println("Alarm will go off next day");
            }
       #Set alarm here using "triggerMillis"
        .........................
         ...........................
}
```